# How to aggregate when using populate virtuals in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to use mongoose's [populate virtuals](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). Let's say I have this Post schema:

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});
postSchema.virtual('comments', {
  ref: 'Comment',
  foreignField: '_id',
  localField: 'post'
});
```

Now, let's say I wanted to filter by the comment content using `aggregate`:

```
Post.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [{ 'comments.content': /match this content/ }]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: { title: 1, comments: 1 }
  }
)]
```

This doesn't work because `comments` hasn't been populated. Any alternatives?

Comment: Normally you would use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to join comments and then filter comments.

Comment: @Veeram, right so something like `$lookup: {
          from: 'comments',
          localField: 'comments',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'comments'
        }` Unfortunately it doesn't return any comments

Comment: Looks like `localField` is an array. Try {`$unwind: "$comments"}` before `$lookup` and see if it helps. `$unwind` not required starting in 3.4 version.

Comment: I tried that as well–it returns an empty array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do as :

```
Post.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup:{
      from:"comments",
      localField:"_id",
      foreignField:"post",
      as:"comments"
    },
    $unwind:{
      "$comments"
    },
    $match: {
      $or: [{ 'comments.content': /match this content/ }]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: { title: 1, comments: 1 }
  }
)]`
```

Comment: It turns out I had the local and foreign fields flipped. I just updated your answer. Thanks!